# AppCompatActivity with the new Toolbar having Home button not shown correctly?

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android, android-toolbar

***This question involves Xamarin Android and using C#***, but I think Java developer using Android Studio ... can still understand the problem and may help.

As I have researched on the net, everything should be simple. The problem here is the `Toolbar` (in v7 support library) shows at the top expectedly but the Home button does not show as what I want.
I have a `DrawerLayout` in the main layout, clicking on the Home button should expand the drawer layout and together with that the Home icon should switch to the left arrow icon (back icon). 
Clicking the back button should collapse the drawer layout and switch the icon back to the Home's initial icon.

What I had now is the Home button always shows the left arrow icon. I think that's because I use the call `SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`
But without setting like that there is not anything shown, so there is nothing to click on.

Here is the code resulting in a working Home button but its Icon always shows the left arrow:

***The Toolbar layout***:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainToolbar"    
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"                                   
    android:layout_height="@dimen/ToolbarHeight">  
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

***The code behind***:

```
//here is in OnCreate callback of the main Activity
var toolBar = FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.mainToolbar);
SetSupportActionBar(toolBar);
SupportActionBar.SetDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);            
SupportActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

With the above code, if I commment out the line `SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` then there is nothing shown (while I want some Icon such as the 
app icon to be shown).

I hope someone here could figure out what I miss here.
BTW I run the code on Android 4.4.4, although I think this is not the problem of Android version (because the support library should work in this case).

***UPDATE***:
The main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/rootFrame"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">
  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
      android:id="@+id/main"                                        
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      >  
      <!-- main content -->
      <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainContent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <include layout="@layout/MainToolBar"/>
        <FrameLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                   android:id="@+id/contentFrame"></FrameLayout>
      </LinearLayout>

      <!-- left menu -->
      <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView    
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth="@dimen/LeftMenuMinWidth"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
            android:background="@color/LeftMenuBackgroundColor"    
            android:id="@+id/leftMenu">
            <!-- layout for the menu here ... -->
      </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
  </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

***Code to setup the drawer listener***, this is placed after the code setting the toolBar I posted above:

```
var dl = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.main);
//the ActionBarDrawerToggle here is from Android.Support.V7.app
dl.AddDrawerListener(new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, dl, toolBar, 0, 0));
```

I hope now I have provided enough code.

Comment: @MikeM. I do set the listener, that's why I said the Home button works (but its Icon keeps being shown as a left arrow), the drawer is collapsed/expanded OK (that when I use `SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`) but without using that, nothing is shown and nothing to click on. Thanks.

Comment: The `DrawerListener` interface isn't what opens/closes the drawer. It's what allows the icon to animate. Please post the relevant code for your toggle.

Comment: Oh, and the `SetDisplayShowHomeEnabled()` call isn't necessary, but I can't recall atm if that would interfere with the toggle's icon.

Comment: @MikeM. please see my update, acually I think the listener works because it partly controls the drawer layout.

Comment: @MikeM. If you mean that `SetDisplayShowHomeEnabled()` might interfere with the toggle's Icon, I also tried removing that line, nothing changes.

Comment: As I mentioned, the `DrawerListener` interface doesn't open/close the drawer. Clicking does that. Also, you need to call `SyncState()` on the toggle, otherwise it'll never set its icon on the nav button.

Comment: @MikeM. well that's the `SyncState` making it work. Please add your answer, I'll accept it. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using an `ActionBarDrawerToggle`, you need to call `SyncState()` on it after initialization to cause it to actually set its own icon on the navigation button.

It's also recommended to do this in the `Activity`'s `OnPostCreate()` method, so it can sync correctly if, for example, the drawer is open during a device rotation.